# In Python How I can save Naive Bayes, SVM, RF and DT Classification for final predictions for all samples saved as a .csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning

I would like to save predicted output as a CSV file. In Python, how can I save Naive Bayes, SVM, RF and DT Classification for final predictions for all samples saved as a `.csv` file with three columns, namely Sample, Actual value, Prediction values.

My code is as follows:

```
pred_scores = []

for i in np.linspace(0.05, 1, num=20):    
    mnb = MultinomialNB(alpha=i)
    mnb.fit(features_train, labels_train)
    pred = mnb.predict(features_test)
    pred_scores.append((i, [accuracy_score(labels_test,pred)]))

df = pd.DataFrame.from_items(pred_scores,orient='index', columns=['Score'])

df.plot(figsize=(11,6))

print(df[df['Score'] == df['Score'].max()])

df_NB=df['Score'].max()
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a 3 column df where each columns corresponds to 'Sample', 'Actual Value', and 'Predicted Value'. Afterwards, run the following command:

```
df.to_csv('foo.csv', index = False) #If you would like to remove the default index
```